# Multiple conditions in one query separated by OR operator in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Basic question. In SQL, is there a quicker way to list conditions in a SELECT statement using the OR operator?

At the moment I'm writing multiple conditions in my statements like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE City = 'Berlin' OR City = 'London' OR 
City = 'Dublin';
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this, without having to write 'City =' for each condition, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE c.City IN ('Berlin', 'London', 'Dublin');
```

In addition to being more concise, this is more efficient for long lists as well.  MySQL sorts the list of values and uses a binary search for long lists -- much more efficient than a sequential search under most circumstances.